# Firebase Realtime Database OnSnapShot functionality through REST?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am making a react-native (expo) chat app. Throughout the app including Auth-work , Users-work, etc, I have used  Firebase Rest API to do all the work. Now in the messaging section, I am using `react-native-gifted-chat` I have made the sending messaging functionality and I am storing my Messages like this.

[FireBase storing Messaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5yoc.png)

Like in the firebase package, we can do something like `onSnapshot()` but is there a way to do the same In the rest API. If not, what should I do if I don't want to install firebase and only work through rest API.
In Conclusion:
**I want to ask is there a way in firebase rest API to do something when a node changes (like `Chatroom` node)**

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to listen for updates through REST, you can use the [streaming REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming), which delivers this functionality through Event Source/Server Sent Events.

Implementing this is typically quite a bit more involved than using a Firebase SDK, so if an SDK is available for your platform, I recommend using that.